# Alignment issue with full calendar popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar, fullcalendar

Am re sizing the height of the full calendar to fit in my screen. And am also limiting the events displayed in month view. So, now when I click +'x'more button, event container popup is coming at the bottom of the screen.

If am not altering the height, event container popup is aligned properly.

Please let me know how to fix popup alignment issue when calendar height is re sized.

Below is my code and attached the screenshot of calendar view

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  now: new Date(),
  editable: false,
  aspectRatio: 1.8,
  height: 200,
  selectable: true,
  scrollTime: '00:00',
  header: {
    left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'timelineDay,timelineThreeDays,agendaWeek,month'
  },
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
    if (view.name == 'month') {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date._d.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', "timelineDay");
    }
  },
  defaultView: 'timelineDay',
  views: {
    timelineThreeDays: {
      type: 'timeline',
      duration: {
        days: 3
      }
    }
  },
  eventOverlap: false,
  resourceAreaWidth: '25%',
  resourceLabelText: 'Reservations',
  resourceGroupField: 'building',
  resources: resourcesList,
  events: eventList,
  eventLimit: true,
  eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.find('.fc-title').append('&nbsp;&nbsp;' + event.statusCode);
  },

});
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2ZaS.png)

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: No.. couldn't solve this. If height of calendar is changed we will have this alignment issue.